# How to replace HashMap Values while iterating over them in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, runnable

I am using a Runnable to automatically subtract 20 from a players cooldown every second, but I have no idea how to replace the value of a value as I iterate through it. How can I have it update the value of each key?

```
public class CoolDownTimer implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (Long l : playerCooldowns.values()) {
            l = l - 20;
            playerCooldowns.put(Key???, l);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 145, accepted):

**Using Java 8:**

```
map.replaceAll((k, v) -> v - 20);
```

---

**Using Java 7 or older:**

You can iterate over the entries and update the values as follows:

```
for (Map.Entry<Key, Long> entry : playerCooldowns.entrySet()) {
    entry.setValue(entry.getValue() - 20);
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks.

Comment: Actually there is a FindBugs-Warning for that pattern: _Inefficient use of keySet iterator instead of entrySet iterator_ And even if it doesn't matter in most cases, performance wise, it can make huge difference in some cases. Besides, I even think the code is clear and readable in both cases. Why use and post a pattern that clearly has some disadvantages and no advantage whatsoever? (Even if the disadvantages are arguably small)

Comment: @aioobe: I can imagine that this has different effects on different map implementation, sure, but is there one where the former form of iterating is more efficient then the latter? And therefore the FindBugs-Warning would be a false-positive? But you're right, we don't have to discuss that here. You answer is still okay, I guess.

Comment: Can you explain why this works? As I recall, you are not allowed to change elements of a collection while you iterator over them using a for each loop.

Comment: You're not allowed to do *structural* changes such as adding or removing elements.

Comment: @AlexLi The values of a hashmap do not influence the structure. You cannot change the keys of the hashmap, but you can change the values. Inserting and removing items is not allowed, thus you cannot change the key of an entry. The iterator often allows you to remove items though, because it has knowledge of the underlying structure and can prevent bad things from happening (skipping items, double-iterating items, iterating over random garbage, etc.).

Comment: As mentioned above I believe the keySet loop in the java 7 section to be wrong. As specified in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet-- the behavior of the iteration is undefined if the map is changed - which it could be using put, even if the key remains constant. The entry set example does not have the same flaw, as that is modifying the value directly, which is allowed by https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--

Comment: @KasperNielsen good point. If it's the same restriction as for lists this refers to structural modifications (addition / removal of entries). Regardless, I've updated the answer to be on the safe side here. The `entrySet` is probably faster anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

Well, you can't do it by iterating over the set of values in the `Map` (as you are doing now), because if you do that then you have no reference to the keys, and if you have no reference to the keys, then you can't update the entries in the map, because you have no way of finding out which key was associated with the value you just updated.

When working with Maps, you have two options for updates like this, iterate through each `Map.Entry<K,V>` in the `Map`, or you can iterate through the key `Set`. There are methods on `Map` to do both of these things. Personally, I would iterate through each `Map.Entry<K,V>`.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : playerCooldowns.entrySet()) {
    entry.setValue(entry.getValue() - 20);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Why not iterate over the [Map.Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) objects ? Each `Entry` will give you the key and value and you don't have to perform an additional `get()` on the `Map` to get a value.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to add value to unmodifiable map then you will get `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`. If you are using unmodifiable map then you need to do like below.

```
Map<String, Object> modifiableMap = new HashMap<>(unmodifiableMap);

// Update the value of a key in the new map
modifiableMap.put("new key1", "new value");
```