# How to traverse and update a Collection like HashMap in java dynamically?

Tags: java, hashmap

I need a data structure like `HashMap` or any other `Collection`, which will be updated during the traversal. I tried to traverse `HashMap`, `ConcurrentHashMap` and `LinkedHashMap` using `Iterator`, but I am not able get result. Snippet of the code is:

```
Map<String, String> linkscoll = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
linkscoll.put("ABC", "ABC");
for(Iterator it = linkscoll.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
{
   Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
   String temp = (String) entry.getValue();
   System.out.println(temp);
   linkscoll.put("DEF", "DEF");
}
```

My output should be: 
ABC 
DEF

But it is giving output as
ABC

I am really need of this. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Please share your code and point out where you get stucked.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean, but it looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993403/how-to-replace-hashmap-values-while-iterating-over-them-in-java

Comment: Use  a concurrent-hashmap instead of hashmap

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterate through a HashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap)

Comment: If I interpreted what you mean by "updated inside its traversal loop" correctly, then this is a possible duplicate of [iterating over and removing from a map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884889/iterating-over-and-removing-from-a-map)

Comment: I can't answer to you because the query is still [on hold]. But the idea is to create an “ArrayDequeue<String> toDo”, when you insert into the map also insert into the queue. And do not iterate over map, extract from the queue until queue is empty. This is: linkscoll.put("ABC", "ABC"); toDo.add(“ABC”); while(!toDo.isEmpty()) { String url = toDo.poll();  System.out.println(url); linkscoll.put("DEF", "DEF"); toDo.add(“DEF”);}. And don't forget to check if an element is in the map before adding it to the queue if you want to avoid revisiting old elements.

Comment: This query is not a duplicate of “iterating over and removing from a map” because kravi wants to add (not remove) in a traversal loop. And Iterator interface defines a “remove” method but not an “add” one. Only ListIterator interface include "add" semantic, but maps return sets (for traversal) not lists.

Comment: @acesargl Really a good idea you gave me. And thanks to understand my query properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can with a plain `HashMap`. It is possible to iterate a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) because it preserves insertion order. The linked `LinkedHashMap` Javadoc says (in part)

> The iterators returned by the `iterator` method of the collections returned by all of this class's collection view methods are *fail-fast*: if the map is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own `remove` method, the iterator will throw a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html). Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `iterator (java.util.Iterator)` ([See Here](http://tutorialswithexamples.com/how-to-iterate-through-map-or-hashmap-in-java/)) 
But if you want to modify anything then you have to do it using the iterator only otherwise you will get `concurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (Map.Entry<KeyObject, ValueObject> entry : yourHashMap.entrySet()){
    ValueObject thisObject = entry.getValue();
    ///Do stuff to thisObject
}
```